# $f$ a real sub linear function, prove that: $\partial f(a)= \left \{ z \in \partial f(0) | z\cdot a = f(a) \right \}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, convex-geometry, subgradient

Question:
Let $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ a sub [linear function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sublinear_function) and $ a \in \mathbb{R^n}$. We have to prove that:  $\partial f(a)= \left \{ z \in \partial f(0) | z\cdot a = f(a) \right \}$

I am really stuck here as I ve tried different ways to prove it. By induction, prove of the type $A \subseteq B$ and $B \subseteq A$ to conclude $A=B$, but i didn't succeed in all of them.
Any details answer will be very helpful as I have no one to ask.

Thank

Comment: $f(a)$ is just a  point in $\mathbb R$ isn't it?

Comment: @Bongo yes tottaly

Comment: @X0-user-0X This isn't too difficult, so let's do some hints. For the $\supseteq$ direction, try first writing down what it means for $z \in \partial f(0)$, remembering that $f(0) = 0$. Now try writing down what it means for $z \in \partial f(a)$, under the assumption that $z \cdot a = f(a)$. For the $\subseteq$ direction, you begin by assuming $z \cdot (x - a) \le f(x) - f(a)$ for all $x$. Try substituting $x = \lambda a$ for specific $\lambda > 0$. Try some $\lambda > 1$, and try some $\lambda < 1$. Use sublinearity.

Comment: @TheoBendit thank you for your answer. As I ve told in my post I am stuck on the method to prove with the inclusion. Indeed I am stuck here: $\partial f(0) = \left \{ z\in \mathbb{R}^n|f(y) \geq z\cdot y, \forall y \in \mathbb{R}^n \right \}$. I suppose that it should be equal to $\mathbb{R}^n$ but how can I justify it?

Comment: @X0-user-0X No, it won't be $\Bbb{R}^n$. But, if $f(a) = z \cdot a$, then $f(y) \ge z \cdot y$ if and only if $f(y) - f(a) \ge z \cdot y - z \cdot a$. Does that help?

Comment: @TheoBendit again thk you for your time but not a lot. As I told I ve tried this type of "inclusion" before without succeed

Comment: The condition $f(y) - f(a) \ge z \cdot y - z \cdot a$, for all $y$, is the definition of $z \in \partial f(a)$. So, the assumptions $z \in \partial f(0)$ and $f(a) = z \cdot a$ combine to give $z \in \partial f(a)$, i.e. $\{z \in \partial f(0) : z \cdot a = f(a)\} \subseteq \partial f(a)$.  This gives us the $\supseteq$ conclusion. Are you with me so far?

Comment: @TheoBendit yes thank you

Comment: So, now try the other inclusion. You know that $z \in \partial f(a)$ if and only if $f(y) - f(a) \ge z \cdot (y - a)$, for all $y$. Try substituting $y = \lambda a$ for some $\lambda > 0$. Try picking a value of $\lambda$ that is greater than $1$, to begin with. What does the inequality tell you (remembering $f(\lambda a) = \lambda f(a)$)?

Comment: @TheoBendit Thank a lot for your help in time can you check if the demo  I ve written is correct. Again sorry for the time I ve taken you but for some reasons today I was not that much in focus. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank a lot to @Theo Bendit

*1/ Prove that: $\left \{ z \in \partial f(0) | z.a =f(a) \right \} \subseteq \partial f(a)$*
By definition $\partial f(0) =\left \{ z \in \mathbb{R}^n | f(y) \geq f(0)+z\cdot (y-0), \forall y \in \mathbb{R}^n \right \}=\left \{ z \in \mathbb{R}^n | f(y) \geq z\cdot y , \forall y \in \mathbb{R}^n \right \} $. As by definition of a sub linear function we have: $f(0)=f(0\cdot x)=0f(x)=0$.
Now if $z \in \partial f(0)$ by definition we have that $f(y) \geq z\cdot y, \forall y \in \mathbb{R}^n$.
And on this set of $z \in \partial f(0)$ by assumption we only take the "$z$" s.t.  $f(a)=z \cdot a$.
So we get the following inequation $f(y)-f(a) \geq z \cdot y - z \cdot a, \forall y \in \mathbb{R^n} $
But pay attention to the fact that by definition $\partial f(a) = \left \{ z \in \mathbb{R}^n | f(y) \geq f(a)+z \cdot (y-a), \forall y \in \mathbb{R}^n \right \}=\left \{ z \in \mathbb{R}^n | f(y) - f(a)\geq z \cdot y- z \cdot a, \forall y \in \mathbb{R}^n \right \}$ so in particular when $z \in \partial f(0) \Rightarrow \left \{ z \in \partial f(0) | z.a =f(a) \right \} \subseteq \partial f(a)$

*2/ Prove that: $ \partial f(a) \subseteq \left \{ z \in \partial f(0) | z.a =f(a) \right \}$*
We know that $z \in \partial f(a)$ iff $f(y)-f(a) \geq z \cdot (y-a) , \forall y \in\mathbb{R}^n $. If it is true $\forall y$ it is true in particular when $y=\lambda a, \lambda >0$. We get: $f(y)-f(a)=f(a)(\lambda -1) \geq z \cdot (y-a)=z \cdot a (\lambda -1)$
When $\lambda >1 \Rightarrow f(a) \geq z \cdot a$ and this is exactly the definition for $z$ in order to belong to $\partial f(0), \forall a$. And it is especially the case when $f(a) = z \cdot a$ and in such a case this $z \in \left \{ z \in \partial f(0) | z.a =f(a) \right \}$.
When $\lambda <1   \Rightarrow f(a) \leq z \cdot a$ and in the special case when $f(a)=z \cdot a$ we have that this $z \in \left \{ z \in \partial f(0) | z.a =f(a) \right \}$
When $\lambda =1 $  we get $f(0)=0$ and after it is trivial.

Q.E.D.

Comment: Yes, this is correct.